# Store address information

Tags: c

I have a question about the following code:

```
//Definition of base used in ptr
void *base; 

int query(Win *ptr, void *baseptr)
{
    *(void**) baseptr = ptr->base;
    ...
}
```

Can I simply change the statement to the following?

```
baseptr = ptr->base;
```

Why does it cast `baseptr` to `void **`?

Comment: It's likely that there is some interface that `query()` is required to implement. Could we have the information on how `query()` is used?

Comment: No, you can't, since `*(void **)baseptr` is not the same thing as `baseptr`. The former dereferences `baseptr` and stores a value in the memory it points to. The latter does not dereferences it, instead it stores the value (which happens to be a pointer) in `baseptr` itself.

Comment: @BillLynch the example given by timrau is exactly how its used in the code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `baseptr` is used as output parameter. The caller of `query()` should looks like:

```
void *base = NULL;
Win *win = something;
int result = query(win, &base);
```

Then, `base` in the caller function may be assigned the received value.

If you just write `baseptr = ptr->base;`, then it is the *copy* of `base` *inside* `query()` being updated. After `query()` returns, the pointer in caller is not updated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have overlooked the first * before the cast. It dereferences the pointer baseptr. This means, that the value of ptr->base is stored at the address where baseptr POINTS TO, and NOT in baseptr ITSELF. The cast happens because it tells the compiler that baseptr is now a pointer to another void pointer (i.e. the void pointer ptr->base).